# Got packets out of order

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am running a Wordpress website on local with MAMP, so when I try to call it:

```
http://localhost:8889/myfoldername/
```

I got this message:

```
J���
5.5.29����l9ubijVS�ÿ÷�€����������z.s|65HJzI<0�mysql_native_password�!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order
```

I verified the DB on phpMyAdmin, also, MAMP use the `8889` so I changed it in `wp-config.php`. What I am missing? Thanx.

Comment: It sounds like you pointed your web browser directly to the mysql server instead of the web server. Which port are your web server running on, which are your mysql server running on ?

Comment: Hi, mysql server port is `3306` and my web server port is `8888`

Answer (score 0):

Just point to `http://localhost:8888/myfoldername/` in your installation and you should be able to hit the apache serving your wordpress.